# How to access td tag and innertext of a web page

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a web page in java script on that i have elements which is a innertext of element that is in td tag.

Comment: Please post HTML sample.

Comment: Please rephrase your statement in the form of a question. :)

Comment: What is "How to access td tag and innertext of a web page"? for the game-show fans in the audience. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have understood the question properly, but here is some info which might be helpful.

To select TD (Table Cell):

```
$browser.cell(:id, "leftcolumn")
```

And to get the innerText of any element or page:

```
$browser.cell(:id, "leftcolumn").text
```

So if you want to find the inner text of a cell, here is a example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

$browser = Watir::IE.start("http://www.w3schools.com/")
$browser.speed = :fast
$browser.bring_to_front
$browser.maximize

left_col = $browser.cell(:id, "leftcolumn").text
puts left_col.text
puts left_col.html
```

Please notice .html will return the inner html of the element.

Hope this helps.

Regards, 
Vishalgiri Goswami